# Forked ptraced process hangs

Tags: linux, unix, go

I am trying to intercept syscalls when calling a program from Go, however I'm running into two issues.

The child seems to hang, which hangs the parent process as well. It seems `wait4(2)` is blocking which seems weird, wouldn't the child finally call `exit(2)` to exit?

The syscalls I get to `stdout` are not consistent, sometimes the last syscall is `3`, other times it's `6` or `192`. Do I have a race condition in my code? Why does this happen?

I tried listening for signals on the parent, but I don't receive anything..

I've substituted the program I usually run with `/bin/ls`.

```
package main

import (
  "syscall"
  "fmt"
  "os/signal"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
  signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
  go SignalListener(c)

  attr := new(syscall.ProcAttr)
  attr.Sys = new(syscall.SysProcAttr)
  attr.Sys.Ptrace = true

  pid, err := syscall.ForkExec("/bin/ls", nil, attr)

  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  var wstat syscall.WaitStatus
  var regs syscall.PtraceRegs

  for {
    fmt.Println("Waiting..")
    _, err := syscall.Wait4(pid, &wstat, 0, nil)
    fmt.Printf("Exited: %d\n", wstat.Exited())

    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      break
    }

    syscall.PtraceGetRegs(pid, &regs);
    fmt.Printf("syscall: %d\n", regs.Orig_eax)

    syscall.PtraceSyscall(pid, 0)
  }
}

func SignalListener(c <-chan os.Signal) {
  s := <-c

  fmt.Printf("Got signal %d\n", s)
}
```

Comment: It's not good idea to fork in multi-thread world. See [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.go.general/112782)

Comment: @janisz "func ForkExec: Combination of fork and exec, careful to be thread safe." eh... no. ForkExec has been specified exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that intercepting syscalls with Go is going to be very difficult, and anything ptrace will probably not work.

Go has a runtime which multiplexes go-routines onto OS threads. A syscall is a scheduling point, so after the syscall returns you could be on a different thread, whereas I think ptrace follows a single thread.

Say the thread you are ptrace-ing is running your main go-routine. Then you call fmt.Println (which does syscall.Write), so the Go runtime takes your go-routine off that thread, and runs the syscall in a different os thread (syscalls always run in different threads). When the syscall returns, your main go-routine is put back on the schedulers list of runnable routines, and it will continue on whichever os thread is available, which may not be the one you are ptrace-ing.

This is also the reason you cannot step through a Go program with `gdb`.

If you just wanted to execute an external program (like /bin/ls) you could use [os/exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) from the standard library.

The program that comes closes to what you are trying to do is probably [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve). I think that sets a breakpoint on every thread at each single-step, then tries to find which thread your go-routine is now on based on the go-routine id.

Comment: I realize this answer is 5 years old, but I am facing this issue now. Would using [`runtime.LockOSThread()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) solve the issue you write about here?

Comment: It might. You could try `LockOSThread()` in `init` and step through your `main` function with gdb, see if it works. If that doesn't work I'd recommend looking at what Delve does, but I'm guessing it will be complicated.

Comment: The [golang syscall source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ba9e10889976025ee1d027db6b1cad383ec56de8/src/syscall/exec_linux.go#L25-L27) instructs users to call `LockOSThread()` before using ptrace.